# Supported long-distance RFID passive tags on android phones with NFC?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

Is there any way for an Android phone with NFC (Nexus, Galaxy, etc.) to read a passive RFID tag that was designed for longuer distances reads? I'm interested in using a same tag that can be read by a RFID reader at a longuer distance and a Android Phone with NFC at a shorter distance.

Does such a tag exist? Is so, how can I read and write it with the Android SDK since it's not a typical NFC tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Nexus devices with NFC all support ISO15693 tags. ISO15693 tags are vicinity tags and offer maximum read distance of 1-1.5 metres (depending on the reader antenna). The Nexus devices have a read range for these tags comparable with other NFC tags: a couple of cm at the most.

Android supports NDEF content stored on some ISO15693 tags: the [NXP ICODE](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/smart_label_and_tag_ics/icode/) range of products. Android's `Ndef` technology class will take care of the reading and writing from/to such tags and automatic discovery, like for other NFC tags. For a non-Android reader details on how NDEF is stored on ICODE tags is described in http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11042.pdf and http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11032.pdf.

Comment: Great, thanks! Yet, I can't find any ICODE SLI ISO15693 tags out there that can go up to 1-1.5 metres. All the 13.56 MHz tags I see only go up to 10 cm. Do you have any examples?

Comment: The ISO15693 will go up to 1-1.5 meters if you are willing to use an antenna of roughly the size of a ping-pong paddle. Oh, and you need a transceiver IC with a more beefy RF output. The chips in NFC phones are optimized for low power and can't output that much RF.

Comment: So I suppose it would not help to attach a larger antenna to my phone in the hope, that it will improve the range significantly? :)

Comment: Don't count on it: if there is any improvement, it will be very small. The power that the NFC controller can deliver remains the same, after all.

Answer (score 0):

The Antenna of NFC Mobile Devices will detect only in range of Centimeters. 4-10 cm possibly.

Can you please explain why you want such thing to work ?